# Can't load image using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I created a project with JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 5.
Now I want to integrate Bootstrap 3.3.7 to my project so I added those files:
[Bootstrap Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVSL7.png)

```css
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 
 <h:head>
     <f:facet name="first">
         <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Conpatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
            <title>SARSOURA | Example</title>
  </f:facet>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{resource['icons/hki2.gif']}"/>
    </h:head>
 <body>
 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
              <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="b.jpg" alt="125x125"/>
              </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
              <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="b.jpg" alt="125x125"/>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

After running the project, the following page appears without showing the images a.jpg and b;jpg.
Have you please any idea about solving this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's depending on where are store your picture. With you're configuration, you must set them into the root directory that contains this file (perhaps you've a Apache or Nginx configure upon so choose the right dir)

Comment: This is not related to PrimeFaces or JSF (or javascript or CSS or twitter-boortstrap)

Comment: Hello @cmizzi Thanks a lot for your reply, I store my pictures under WebContent as the above screenshot displays, if you don't mind, could you please tell me if it's right.